# Comparing two dictionaries and returning the differences in another dictionary

Tags: c#, data-structures, dictionary, .net-4.0

I have two dictionaries and I wish to compare the two dictionaries key / pair values. When I compare them if the value is different in the second dictionary I want to keep their pairing and store that into dictionary3.

So if I have dictionary 1 with (`<1,T><2,T><3,T>`) and 2 with (`<1,T><2,F><3,T>`) I want 3 to look like (`<2,F>`).

I am not sure where to start with this one. I have the dictionaries properly getting all their data but right now I am not sure how to set up the compare.

```
private Dictionary<int, bool> CompareDictionaries(Dictionary<int, bool> dic2)
{
    Dictionary<int,bool> dictionary3 = new Dictionary<int,bool>();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, bool> pair in dictionary1)
    {
        // keep KeyValuePair of dic2
        // dictionary3.add(KeyValuePair of dic 2)
    }

    return dictionary3;
}
```

Any help on this would be appreciated. I am pretty positive that I can accomplish my goal with dictionaries. Down the line after I get the 3rd dictionary I am going to update some information in a table and then refresh a list I am displaying but that part is much easier then figure out what methods and algorithm I need for this part. Any help is as always very very appreciated. Thank guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var dict3 = dict2.Except(dict1).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: do we need `ToDictionary` here?

Comment: @KingKing Since the OP says he wants the results in a dictionary, and not an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>`, yes.

Comment: @Servy what about this `private Dictionary<int, bool> CompareDictionaries(Dictionary<int, bool> dic2)`? `dict2` is `Dictionary` but `dictionary1` is `KeyValuePair`.

Comment: @KingKing `Dictionary<K,V>` *implements* `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K,V>>`.  All dictionaries are sequences, not all sequences are dictionaries.  Treating a dictionary as a sequence is fine, treating a sequence as a dictionary is not.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Going to give this a shot and see. I never really seen notation like this before. Is this something specific I can look up and get more familiar with. This just looks clean and possible a better practice then what I was going to use.

Comment: @NitroFrost I think you need to read some docs about [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx) + [Lambda](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
return dictionary1.Where(kvp => dic2[kvp.Key] != kvp.Value)
    .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => dic2[kvp.Key]);
```

This will throw up if dictionary 1 contains any key not present in dictionary 2. Not sure if that would be the intended business functionality from the question.

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar, but returned an anonymous type instead of a Dictionary because I wanted to see the deltas clearly

```
var aBeforeDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(){ {"asdf", "asdf"}, {"few","less"}, {"curve", "ball"}};
var anAfterDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(){ {"asdf", "asdf"}, {"fun", "guy"}, {"few","more"}};

var myBefores = aBeforeDictionary.Except(anAfterDictionary);
var myAfters = anAfterDictionary.Except(aBeforeDictionary);

var affectedKeys = myBefores.Select(aPair => aPair.Key).Union(myAfters.Select(aPair => aPair.Key));

string aValue;
var output = affectedKeys.Select(aKey => new {
                                 Key = aKey,
                                 Before = aBeforeDictionary.TryGetValue(aKey, out aValue) ? aValue : "",
                                 After = anAfterDictionary.TryGetValue(aKey, out aValue) ? aValue : ""
                             });

output.Dump();
```

The Dump() syntax is a LinqPad extension method. Here are the results:

[image: Expected results]

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt ;-)

```
    private Dictionary<int, bool> CompareDictionaries(Dictionary<int, bool> dic1, Dictionary<int, bool> dic2)
    {
        Dictionary<int, bool> dic3 ;

        dic3  = new Dictionary<int, bool>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, bool> pair in dic1)
        {
            // keep KeyValuePair of dic2
            if ( ! ((dic2.ContainsKey(pair.Key)) && (dic2[pair.Key] == pair.Value)))
            {
                dic3.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
            }
        }
        return dic3;
    }
```

Comment: You can use `TryGetValue` to perform the ContainsKey check and the value lookup in a single call.

Comment: @Servy thanks...anyway the LINQ solution is so clean that any other answer will look bad ;-)

Comment: No, This may or may not be useful for OP, but people under .net2.0 definitely needs solution like this

Comment: I am using 4.0. I guess I should tag it that way shouldn't I?